# Как в VisualCode забиндить так чтобы при нажатии прописывался заготовленный код?

Tags: visual-studio, emmet

Как в VisualStudio забиндить, так чтобы при нажатии горячих клавиш прописывался заготовленный код? Мне в частности нужно чтобы при нажатии назначенных горячих клавиш прописывался:`введите сюда код <?php ?> и <?= ?>`,надоело на эти "карючки" время тратить) Спасибо.